# count of max values in sql

Tags: sql

this may be a silly question but I'm getting an error.

This table has a user and their high score.

```
user  |   score  |
__________________
  a        5
  a        7
  a        2
  b        0
  b        8
  b        3
  b        8
  c        5
  c        3
  c        5
  c        2
```

I'm trying to get a list of those with duplicate/triplicate high scores.

so the output here would be

```
user  |   count( max score)  |
_______________________
  a             1
  b             2
  c             2
```

my apologies if this has already been asked, I could not find the answer

Comment: You're getting an error? What's the error? What did you try? 

These would all be helpful things to improve the question so we can understand the pain point

Comment: Please provide more information on your issue. Such things as what you have tried, what has worked and what has not worked along with any scripts and/or error messages. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select user, score, cnt
from (select user, score, count(*) as cnt,
             max(score) over (partition by user) as max_score
      from t
      group by user, score
     ) t
where score = max_score
```

Comment: This worked, thank you for answering so quickly!! I definitely need to review window functions.